# Proportion and Rate

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

How do I form a sentence pattern for:

> The more/less X happens, the more/less Y happens
>
> > E.g. The more you stir, the faster the salt dissolves.
> >
> > The colder the weather, the more time it takes for snow to melt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are also several other grammar patterns that express "as one thing changes (grows/increases/decreases/etc.) another thing changes with it" (the key is that both things are **changing**).

1. 名詞 (noun)
2. 動詞の辞書形 (verb in dictionary form)
3. する動詞の名詞 (the noun of a suru-verb)

> - (2 or 3) + につれて  (cannot express volition or intention, but the rest can).
>
>   - アニメが[流行]{≪はや≫}る**につれて**、日本語を学ぶ人が増えてきています。→　As anime is becoming more popular, the number of people learning Japanese is growing.
> - (2 or 3) + にしたがって
>
>   - 警察の調べが進む**にしたがって**、次々と新しい疑問点が出てきた。→　The-more/As the police investigation progressed, new questions kept arising (one after another).
> - (1 or 2) + に伴って【ともなって】
>
>   - 病気の回復**に伴って**、少しずつ働く時間を伸ばしていくつもりだ。→　As I continue to recover from my illness, little-by-little I intend to work longer (and longer) hours.
> - (1 or 2) + とともに
>
>   - 技術の拡大**とともに**、手紙を書くことが衰えていくでしょう。→　As technology continues to expand, writing letters (by hand) will surely decline.

These used to be JLPT ２級 patterns, but since they changed it to the new N1-N5 system, I don't know which level they are anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Anyone who took formal courses on Japanese would have learned this pattern: X-eba X hodo Y.

> The more you stir, the faster the salt dissolves.
>   混ぜれば混ぜるほど塩が混ざるのは早いです。
>
> The colder the weather, the more time it takes for snow to melt.
>   雪が解けるのは寒ければ寒いほど時間がかかります。

Comment: To note: "X-eba" part is optional.

Comment: @sawa Yup, I have asked about that before here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/243/can-x-eba-x-hodo-y-clause-pattern-be-shortened-to-x-hodo-y/255#255