# How should I parse に従がって強制?

Tags: grammar

Good Day!

I am currently translating a Japanese document and I encountered a problem.

I can't find a way to parse 従がって強制 in this sentence:
この文書はChartis SDLCによるHigh Level Designフェイズに従がって強制されている。

I currently have:
This document *_*_ in the High Level Design Phase according to Chartis SDLC.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

This sentence translates as "The document is (made (to be)) mandatory following/in compliance with/as required by High Level Design Phase by Chartis SDLC."

However, to answer your actual question, you would parse it as `～に従って` + `強制`.  The pattern `Noun + に従って` means "following/complying with ～"  (It can has a semi-overlapping meaning to indicate a [dependent process of change](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2528/78)).  So in this case, the whole sentence parses thus:

> この文書は [  (Chartis SDLCによるHigh Level Designフェイズ)  に従がって]  強制されている

Answer (score 0):

Well, put literally it means "in obedience to coercion".  In context, it would appear to be something along the lines of "In accordance with..." or "In compliance with...", followed by  an organization or a set of standards.

Comment: "complies with" would probably fill the blank in your translation rather well, I think.

Comment: I see. btw, what does がって means here? this is the first time I've seen this word.

Comment: My initial guess is "to feel", my translation was to feel subordinate to coercion. Is this relatively close?

Comment: I think the が might be in there by accident, looking at it.  したがって is the て-form of 従う【したがう】, so I mentally just filled it in.  The 〜がる suffix is usually applied to い-adjectives or the たい-form of verbs (e.g. 従いたがって or 欲しがっている).