# How to make comparisons like "the wider the river the easier to navigate"?

Tags: comparative-constructions

How to make comparisons like "the wider the river the easier to navigate"?

I mean, how to say that because something is this way, something else is that other way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

One pattern you can use is the (〜ば)〜ほど pattern for this, although this is specifically to say that the "something else" depends on the degree (ほど) to which the "something" is.

> - 川の幅が広ければ広いほど、[航行]{こう・こう}しやすくなる　→　The wider the river, the easier it is to navigate
> - あの人の声を聞けば聞くほど、腹が立つ　→　The more I hear that person's voice, the angrier I get
> - となりの可愛い子をみるほど、好きになる　→　The more I see the cute girl next door, the more I like her
> - あきらめないでね。ピアノは練習すればするほど、うまくなるよ！　→　Don't give up.  The more you practice (piano), the better you'll get

There are some more advanced patterns here: [Proportion and Rate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2528/78)