# How to say "as I am doing..."?

Tags: english-to-japanese

How do I say something like, "As I am growing older, I think more and more about the past."?

Especially the "as I am..." part, which has the meaning of "while" but over an extended period of time.

edit:

I am aware of ながら but don't know if it would be valid for me to say

成長しながら、もっともっと子供の時を考える。

(As I am growing older, I think more and more about my childhood.)

Comment: There are many ways to say it.. How about you try to translate it yourself, and we will advise you on how to improve it? Otherwise it would just be a duplicate.

Comment: I have added my "translation" of it, but have doubts on whether or not ながら is correct.

Comment: Related:  [Proportion and Rate](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2528/78).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about 成長するにつれて or 成長すればするほど? And you can say 大人になる or 年を取る instead of 成長する.

In addition, 子供の頃,昔のこと are more natural.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer is close to what I want. It is a bit confusing though, I recommend you separate your two examples with the word "or" instead of a comma. It does seem from some googling though that につれて is what I have been looking for.