# I don't get the difference between ～につれて and ～にしたがって

Tags: grammar

暗くなる**につれて**、気温も下がってきた。

嫌なことがあっても、時間がたつ**にしたがって**、少しずつ忘れていくものだ。

I read these two sentences on my Japanese grammar book. Are ～につれて and ～にしたがって interchangeable? How do I use them?

Comment: 参照:  [Proportion and Rate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2537/78)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my grammar book, につれて and にしたがって can be interchanged without "changing the essential meaning". にしたがって does seem to be used more in writing, while につれて is used more in speaking.

Both of these phrases are used to indicate related change. As in both of the sentences you provided, one thing changes, and another naturally follows.

The verb before these phrases has to indicate some kind of change or movement.

Ok: - indicate change. Many end with てくる or ていく.

> 病気が治ってくるにつれて
>
> 年を取るにつれて
>
> 進んでいくにつれて

dame - no change indicated

> 昼ご飯を食べるにつれて
>
> 英語を教えるにつれて